# Need help to remove carriage return from a text file using batch script

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

e.g

Text file contains data in the vertical form

> a
>
> b
>
> c

Need batch script to convert to following

> a,b,c

Comment: In which OS are you going to do this? Also is it one file or do you need it for multiple files?

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "first=1"
    <nul (
      for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("input.txt") do (
        if defined first (set /p ".=%%a" & set "first=") else (set /p ".=,%%a")
      )
    ) >"output.txt"
```

For each input line, if it is the first, output the line without a line feed, else output a command and the line, also without a line feed.

To supress a line feed, `set /p ".=textToOutput"` is used, but as we are redirecting the input stream to read from `nul`, it will not pause for input but echo the prompt without a line feed and continue.

All the output from the `for` loop is sent to the target file

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f %%a in (file.txt) do (set "string=!string!%%a,")
set "string=%string:~0,-1%"
echo/%string%
pause
```